# How can I set autofocus on an input that react is rendering

Tags: html, reactjs, autofocus

When I set the autofocus attribute on an input I'm returning from a react class the following error is generated:

```
 error TS2339: Property 'autofocus' does not exist on type 'HTMLAttributes'
```

This is the offending code:

```
return <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.text} autofocus/>;
```

I've tried the more verbose `autofocus="autofocus"` with no luck.

Can this be done using react and html? I could set it with javascript but I'd rather a html solution if one exists.

(Edit)
As pointed out by Dominic Tobias, `autoFocus` (case sensitive) on its own does the trick, if you try to set the property like this `autoFocus="autofocus"` you will get the error:

```
TS2322  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with reactjs, but shouldn't you use quotes around the onchange and value like this `value="this.state.text"`? Maybe the browser sees autofocus as part of your value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

React camel-cases [attributes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html#html-attributes). Use:

```
 <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.text} autoFocus />
```